# Solving $\tan(a+b)\tan(b+c)\tan(a+c)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have a simple question :
What are the condition on  $a,b,c$ to have :
$$\tan(a+b)\tan(b+c)\tan(a+c)=1$$
I think we can use the [Huilier formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHuiliersTheorem.html) but I am not sure how to solve it.
Thanks

Edit:

With :
$\tan(a)\tan(b)<1$,
$\tan(a)\tan(c)<1$, and 
$\tan(b)\tan(c)<1$.

My second idea would be to build a cyclic quadrilateral  (convex in your case) with this formulas :

$\tan(\frac{\alpha}{2})\tan(\frac{\beta}{2})=\tan(\frac{\gamma}{2})\tan(\frac{\delta}{2})=1$

With $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=\pi$

On the other hand an other idea would be to use the semiperimeter :

For a cyclic quadrilateral with successive sides $a, b, c, d$ semiperimeter $s$, and angle A between sides $a$ and $d$,we have

$\tan(\frac{A}{2})=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-d)}{(s-b)(s-c)}}$

Comment: what is the meaning of $$a,b,c$$?

Comment: Sorry,$a$,$b$,$c$,are positive real numbers with $tan(a)tan(b)<1$,$tan(b)tan(c)<1$,$tan(c)tan(a)<1$ .

Comment: Is this triangle?

Comment: This is spherical triangle no ?

Comment: There is a link with cyclic quadrilateral [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral)

Comment: You really want to solve $\tan x \tan y \tan z=1$. Then you can take $a=\frac{x+y+z}{2}-y, b=\frac{x+y+z}{2}-z,c=\frac{x+y+z}{2}-x$.

Comment: @FatsWallers Edit your question if you are going to add conditions. The reader should not have to read the comments to figure out the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I edit .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the solutions to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  \tan \left( {a + b} \right)\tan \left( {a + c} \right)\tan \left( {b + c} \right) = 1 \hfill \cr 
  \tan \left( a \right)\tan \left( b \right),\;\tan \left( a \right)\tan \left( c \right),\;\tan \left( b \right)\tan \left( c \right) < 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{1}$$

The equation is symmetric in $a,b,c$, and the solutions will
be centered around the symmetric solution
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
a = b = c = \pi /8
 } $$

This hints to try and make the substitution
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  a + b = \pi /4 + \gamma  \hfill \cr 
  b + c = \pi /4 + \alpha  \hfill \cr 
  a + c = \pi /4 + \beta  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  a = \pi /8 + \left( { - \alpha  + \beta  + \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  b = \pi /8 + \left( {\alpha  - \beta  + \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  c = \pi /8 + \left( {\alpha  + \beta  - \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{2}$$

Making this change of variables we get, for $tan(a+b)$
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\tan \left( {a + b} \right) = \tan \left( {\pi /4 + \gamma } \right) = {{1 + \tan \gamma } \over {1 - \tan \gamma }}
 } \tag{3.a}$$
while for $tan(a)tan(b)$ we get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \tan a\tan b = \tan \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2 - \left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)\tan \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2 + \left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{\tan \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right) - \tan \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)} \over {1 + \tan \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right)\tan \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)}}{{\tan \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right) + \tan \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)} \over {1 - \tan \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right)\tan \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\tan ^{\,2} \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right) - \tan ^{\,2} \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)} \over {1 - \tan ^{\,2} \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right)\tan ^{\,2} \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)}} \cr} 
 } $$

and imposing the condition that $tan(a)tan(b)<1$ we get
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \tan a\tan b < 1\quad  \to \;  \cr 
  &  \to \;\;\tan ^{\,2} \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right) - \tan ^{\,2} \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right) < 1 - \tan ^{\,2} \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right)\tan ^{\,2} \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)\;\; \to   \cr 
  &  \to \;\;\tan ^{\,2} \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right)\left( {1 + \tan ^{\,2} \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)} \right) < 1 + \tan ^{\,2} \left( {\left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)/2} \right)\;\; \to   \cr 
  &  \to \;\;\tan ^{\,2} \left( {\pi /8 + \gamma /2} \right) < 1\;\; \to   \cr 
  &  \to \;\; - 3\pi /4 < \gamma  < \pi /4\quad  \to \quad \tan \gamma  < 1 \cr} 
 } \tag{3.b}$$
and analogously for the other combinations.

So, the original equation is transformed into
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  \tan \left( {a + b} \right)\tan \left( {a + c} \right)\tan \left( {b + c} \right) = 1 \hfill \cr 
  \tan a\tan b,\;\tan a\tan c,\;\tan b\tan c < 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \to   \cr 
  &  \to \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  a + b = \pi /4 + \gamma  \hfill \cr 
  b + c = \pi /4 + \alpha  \hfill \cr 
  a + c = \pi /4 + \beta  \hfill \cr 
  \left( {{{1 + \tan \alpha } \over {1 - \tan \alpha }}} \right)\left( {{{1 + \tan \beta } \over {1 - \tan \beta }}} \right)\left( {{{1 + \tan \gamma } \over {1 - \tan \gamma }}} \right) = 1 \hfill \cr 
   - 3\pi /4 < \alpha ,\;\beta ,\;\gamma  < \pi /4 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \to  \cr} 
 } $$
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
 \to \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  a = \pi /8 + \left( { - \alpha  + \beta  + \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  b = \pi /8 + \left( {\alpha  - \beta  + \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  c = \pi /8 + \left( {\alpha  + \beta  - \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  0 = \tan \alpha  + \tan \beta  + \tan \gamma  + \tan \alpha \tan \beta \tan \gamma  \hfill \cr 
  \tan \alpha ,\;\tan \beta ,\;\tan \gamma  < 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{4}$$

**Conclusion**

Equation (4) tells us that the solutions to (1) are reconducible to the roots of the symmetric polynomial
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
P(x,y,z) = x + y + z + xyz = x\left( {1 + yz} \right) + y + z
 } $$
which can be easily found by expressing one variable in terms of the other two,
and which are rendered graphically by this plot.

[image: Prod_3_Tan_1]

Note the similarity of the solution to the above with the addition formula for $\tanh$
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
x =  - {{y + z} \over {1 + yz}}\quad  \leftrightarrow \quad  - \tanh \left( {c + d} \right) =  - {{\tanh c + \tanh d} \over {1 + \tanh c\tanh d}}
 } $$
which would deserve to be further expanded.

Otherwise, dividing by one of the variables taken to be non-null (e.g., $z$),
the solutions are reconducible to the points on the hyperbola
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
h(\xi ,\eta ;z) = z^{\,2} \xi \eta  + \xi  + \eta  + 1 = 0
 } $$
and we can use the well developed apparatus of conic sections to analyze the behaviour 
of the solutions (existence, axes, canonical form, etc.) and to find appropriated parametric 
representations.

**example :**

In equation (4), choosing $\tan \alpha  = 0,\,\;\tan \beta  = 1/2$ we get $\tan \gamma  =  - 1/2 $, and then

$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \tan \alpha  = 0,\,\;\tan \beta  = 1/2,\;\tan \gamma  =  - 1/2  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \alpha  = 0,\,\;\beta  = \arctan \left( {1/2} \right),\;\gamma  =  - \arctan \left( {1/2} \right)  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  a = \pi /8 \hfill \cr 
  b = \pi /8 - \arctan \left( {1/2} \right) \hfill \cr 
  c = \pi /8 + \arctan \left( {1/2} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \quad \quad  \Downarrow   \cr 
  & \tan \left( {a + b} \right)\tan \left( {a + c} \right)\tan \left( {b + c} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \tan \left( {\pi /4 - \arctan \left( {1/2} \right)} \right)\tan \left( {\pi /4 + \arctan \left( {1/2} \right)} \right)\tan \left( {\pi /4} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {{1 - 1/2} \over {1 + 1/2}}{{1 + 1/2} \over {1 - 1/2}} = 1 \cr} 
 } $$

**addendum**

The similarity with the addition formula for $\tanh$ provides in fact
an interesting parametric equation for $a,b,c$ in terms of $u,v$, which
**for $-\infty<u,v<\infty$ always satisfies the original system (1)**
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left\{ \matrix{
  a = \pi /8 + \left( { - \alpha  + \beta  + \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  b = \pi /8 + \left( {\alpha  - \beta  + \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  c = \pi /8 + \left( {\alpha  + \beta  - \gamma } \right)/2 \hfill \cr 
  \alpha  = \arctan \left( {\tanh u} \right) \hfill \cr 
  \beta  = \arctan \left( {\tanh v} \right) \hfill \cr 
  \gamma  = \arctan \left( {\tanh \left( { - u - v} \right)} \right) =  - \arctan \left( {\tanh \left( {u + v} \right)} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
 } \tag{5}$$

In fact, we have
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\left. {\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \equiv \tan \alpha  + \tan \beta  + \tan \gamma  + \tan \alpha \tan \beta \tan \gamma \; \hfill \cr 
  \tan \alpha ,\;\tan \beta ,\;\tan \gamma  < 1\; \to \;\left\{ \matrix{
  \tanh u,\;\tanh v < 1 \hfill \cr 
   - 1 < \tanh \left( {u + v} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad } \right|\; - \infty  < u,v < \infty 
 } $$

Comment: Your answer seems the most complete and clear. Also the simplicity of the solution is elegant and I think there is nothing wrong. Perhaps I would have a few questions.

Comment: @FatsWallers: glad for the appreciation.  I cleaned up a bit the exposition to make it more fluid. If you have any doubt/ question I'll do my best to answer. Meanwhile I have a question on my side: where does the limitation $tan(a)tan(b)<1$ come from ? (apart from the case in which it is $=1$)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317313/very-hard-hyperbolic-inequality) .

Comment: I saw: much  interesting

Comment: @FatsWallers: have a look at the *addendum*: I suppose it will be much of help for your further application.

Answer (score 0):

By expansion, we get

$$\frac{(\tan(a)+\tan(b))(\tan(b)+\tan(c))(\tan(c)+\tan(a))}{(1-\tan(a)\tan(b))(1-\tan(b)\tan(c))(1-\tan(c)\tan(a))}$$

And as you wrote the multiplication of the terms $\tan(a)\tan(b)<1$ and so on therefore, the denominator is always less than $1$ and hence the whole terms are greater than one. So all the terms 
 $\tan(a+b)\tan(b+c)\tan(c+a)$ have to be $1$. So, $$\tan(a+b)=\tan(b+c)=\tan(c+a)=1$$.

Comment: Why can't the numerator also be less than one?

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan(a+b)\tan(b+c)\tan(a+c)=1 \tag 1$$
$$\tan(b+c)\tan(a+c)=\frac{\cos(b-a)-\cos(b+a+2c)}{\cos(b-a)+\cos(b+a+2c)}$$
$$\tan(a+b)\frac{\cos(b-a)-\cos(b+a+2c)}{\cos(b-a)+\cos(b+a+2c)}=1$$
This can be solved for $\cos(b+a+2c)$
$$\cos(b+a+2c)=\frac{\tan(a+b)-1}{\tan(a+b)+1}\cos(a-b)$$
$$c=\frac{1}{2}\left(-a-b+\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan(a+b)-1}{\tan(a+b)+1}\cos(a-b) \right) \right) \tag 2$$
If we chose arbitrary values of $a$ and $b$, Eq.(2) gives $c$ so that Eq.(1) is satisfied. But $c$ can be complex. To obtain $c$ real, the condition is :
$$-1\leq \frac{\tan(a+b)-1}{\tan(a+b)+1}\cos(a-b) \leq 1$$

On the graph, the areas allowed for $(a,b)$ to achieve $c$ real are drawn in green. The whole is periodic as expected.

[image]

NUMERIAL EXAMPLE :

For example, $a=0.2$ and $b=0.75$

$\frac{\tan(a+b)-1}{\tan(a+b)+1}\cos(a-b)\simeq 0.141608$

$c=\frac{1}{2}\left(-a-b+\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan(a+b)-1}{\tan(a+b)+1}\cos(a-b) \right) \right)\simeq 0.239355$

$\tan(a+b)\tan(b+c)\tan(a+c)\simeq 1.000000$

$\cos^{-1}$ is multi-valuated. Other convenient values of $c$ are obtained, for example $c\simeq 1.952237$

Of course, a numerical example isn't a proof. The analytic proof is above. This shows that one can obtain an infinity of solutions with the above method.